# Declared global var for TS yields semantic error

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a global `log` object. I have declared it in `globals.d.ts`, as follows:

```
declare let log: any;
```

This file is located in a folder `declarations` and my `tsconfig.json` has the following option:

```
"typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./declarations"
    ],
```

I have another declaration in that folder, specific for the framework I am sure that the configurations part is working.

But when trying to transpile, I still get the error

```
<file path>: error TS2304: Cannot find name 'log'.
```

As I was researching, using the `globals.d.ts` file was the *de-facto* way of telling TS about global variables, in order not to puke warnings. Any ideas?

Comment: can you try declaring it with var instead of let?

Comment: Check if this scenario and workaround apply to your situation: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11137#issuecomment-251755605

Answer (score 0):

When working with external modules, your best bet is:

```
declare global {
    let log: any;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I tried changing it to your suggestion (still in the `globals.d.ts` file) but no effect...